# Is the character Johnny based on a real person?

Tags: realism, armageddon-time

According to the film's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon_Time), *Armageddon Time* by James Gray is "inspired by his childhood experiences".

In the movie, there is a character named Johnny Davis, a rebellious African-American classmate of Paul Graff (the protagonist).

Is this character inspired by a real person, and if so, who?